# How do I remove the category from a plotly hovertemplate?

Tags: python, plotly

I have plotted a plotly express "px.scatter_mapbox", and cannot remove the right hand side box indicating the category. I've searched but can't figure out how to remove it (see highlighted box in the image below)

[image: screenshot]).

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(thisplotdf, lat="Latitude", lon="Longitude", 
                        custom_data=['Station', 'Average', 'Compliant'],
                        color="Compliant", 
                        color_continuous_scale="jet",
                        zoom=4.5, height=300,opacity=0.7)

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=20),
                  hovertemplate=("<br>".join([
                      "<b>%{customdata[0]}</b>",
                      "<i>PM2.5 [ug/m3]</i>: %{customdata[1]}",
                      "%{customdata[2]}"])
                                )
                 )
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the tag `<extra></extra>` in the `hovertemplate`:

```
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=20),
                  hovertemplate=("<br>".join([
                      "<b>%{customdata[0]}</b>",
                      "<i>PM2.5 [ug/m3]</i>: %{customdata[1]}",
                      "%{customdata[2]}"])
                                )+"<extra></extra>"
                 )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! What a simple solution to something I spent way too long on!